# Lync 2013 customize contacts' groups

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-server-2010

**In Lync 2010,**

I can customize or select contacts' groups by Stored Procedures in Database-[rtc]

Example:  UserMgmtSetContact UserMgmtAddGroup,UserMgmtGetGroups,UserMgmtGetContacts .....

**But in Lync 2013,**

The Database-[rtc] is not existed, and i can not customize contacts' groups in Lync 2013.

So how can I customize that in Lync 2013, however powershell, SDK, Database, C# ... or anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate a user's contacts and groups via UCMA 4 - via the ContactGroupServices on a UserEndpoint established by a Trusted Application.  There is plenty of documentation available to create such an application, so I will not go further.  If you make changes using this method, the Lync Client will see it immediately.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.contactsgroups.contactgroupservices_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr_members.aspx

Comment: Using the SDK is definately the way to go, stay away from making changes to data and database through sql!